# Remove some specific number from alpha numeric series

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to remove a specific portion from a alpha numeric number for e.g. `1A1234ABCD12345678`.

I would like to separate the numerous part from the last letter (`Example: 1A1234ABCD12345678 TO 12345678`).

Comment: You want to *insert* a space before the trailing digits? What are your requirements and what have you tried?

Comment: what defines a number.  Does it have to end with a number?  Why is 1234 not taken as a number?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, i need last series of number out of any string. Some times string are like A12AD15VEF5656, so i will only need 5656.

Comment: @easymoney202 this is requirement. Extract only last series in any string. Don't care about the rest.

Comment: I don't know, why some one mark my question as -1. Please remove the -1. Ask me question, if i could not justify then mark -1. :(

Comment: I already asked: what have you tried? Questions with just give-me-an-answer statement are usually downvoted and often closed and then removed.

Comment: @MuhammadBashir Do you want to extract all the digits from the string? or just a part of them? I'm not sure I understand waht you mean.

Comment: I have done quit of research. Could not reach to any end. i am blind.

Comment: I agree, the question is still unclear. What is the output for `BBV67BBB`?

Comment: there will always be numeric number in end. In your case, it would be like BBV67BBB8767456. Always numeric value at the end of string. So I need to extract only 8767456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be what you want with a simpler way:

```
string result = Regex.Match(str, @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;
```

Inputs:

```
string str = "BBV67BBB8767456";
//Or
string str = "1A1234ABCD12345678";
```

Outputs:

> 8767456
>
> 12345678

Comment: Come on, it is even simpler: `string result = Regex.Match(str, @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;`

Comment: Yess... this is even more simple

Comment: Even simpler:

string result = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d+)$").Value

Comment: @sheppe: `RightToLeft` lets the engine grab the digits at the end straight away without checking each char from left to right. It is a really cool feature to use in such situations. And a capturing group is totally redundant here, you do not even use it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The $ in the regex has the search match from the end of the line. Does the RightToLeft flag offer better performance?

Comment: @sheppe: The `$` does not tell the regex engine to go straight to the end of line/text and then look there. Regex engines are not that smart. They work like parsers and they parse from left to right (bu default). You have `\d+` first, so each char will be tested if it is a digit, and then if the next can also be matched as a digit. All the text will be processed like this if you do not specify the opposite direction with the right to left option. Then, parsing the string will start from the end, but the subpatterns will be matched as usual, from left to right.

Comment: The $ does return the match from the end of the line (per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx), but I think you are saying that without the RightToLeft flag the search will begin from the left and work to the right and then give us the result we want. Whereas if you do pass the RightToLeft flag, the search will begin on the right and therefore be more performant. If so then this answers my question about it offering better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RegularExpressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
        var str = "1A1234ABCD12345678";
        var regex = new Regex(@"(^.*?)(\d*)$");
        if (regex.IsMatch(str))
        {
            var matches = regex.Matches(str);
            for (int a = 0; a < matches.Count; a++)
            {
                var match = matches[a];
                for (int b = 0; b < match.Groups.Count; b++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Match{0}Group{1}:{2}", a, b, match.Groups[b].Value);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0} {1}", matches[0].Groups[1], matches[0].Groups[2]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The above example loops through all matches and all groups for debugging.  The simplified answer is:

```
var str = "1A1234ABCD12345678";
var regex = new Regex(@"(^.*?)(\d*)$");
if (regex.IsMatch(str))
{
    var matches = regex.Matches(str);
    Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0} {1}", matches[0].Groups[1], matches[0].Groups[2]);
 }
```

References: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Tester: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I appreciate your effort. This really help. It solved my problem.

Comment: no problem!  Regular Expressions are extremely powerful and if you learn how to utilize them, you will be able to solve much more complex problems!

Comment: You might get it with a much better and simpler regex.

Comment: care to provide a better solution?

Comment: I can hint you to it: part of your regex is totally redundant and there is a great modifier flag in .NET that streamlines matching texts close to the end of text. Also, why use `Regex.Matches` if the match will always be single for a given input? No need to use `regex.IsMatch(str)` since you can always check if a match occurred with `Match.Success`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you type more modified Regex ?

Comment: I used this regex since in his original post he wanted a space between the beginning and ending string.  Since his requirements changed, this may not be the simplest regex.  Simpler would be `(\d+$)`

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the trick:

```
var text = "1A1234ABCD12345678";

var lastLetter = text.Where(x => !Char.IsDigit(x)).LastOrDefault();
var lastLetterPosition = text.LastIndexOf(lastLetter);
var divIndex = lastLetterPosition + 1;
var firstPart = new String(text.Take(divIndex).ToArray());
var secondPart = new String(text.Skip(divIndex).Take(text.Length - divIndex).ToArray());

var result = $"{firstPart} {secondPart}";
```

The result is `1A1234ABCD 12345678`.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. This could help, but this is not a smart solution. No doubt it could it could give correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity why it's not smart?

Comment: can you look the answer above your answer. Regix is used to properly extract what is exactly needed. You are trying to achieve all of the goal manually. Problem is, if there is any small change, you will need to redo the whole code. In above solution, you will only need to change Regix. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using regex:

```
string.Join("", YourString.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

Or with linq:

```
var getNumbers = (from t in s
              where char.IsDigit(t)
              select t).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(new string(getNumbers));
```

Or with pure C#:

```
string YourString = "str123";
string NewString= string.Empty;
int val;

for (int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
        b += a[i];
}

if (b.Length>0)
    val = int.Parse(b);
```

Comment: appreciate your effort. But this technique extract all of the digits. My requirement is not this. I need only last series.

Example: 1A1234ABCD12345678 12345678

Comment: @MuhammadBashir on this example what should be the result? '12345678 '?

Comment: i applogize, my mistake. (`Example: 1A1234ABCD12345678 TO 12345678`). this is complete string 1A1234ABCD12345678  i need to extract only last numbers of string 12345678